# Can't prevent file upload on failed validation using jQuery Form plugin

Tags: validation, jquery-forms-plugin

Here's my form:

```
<form id="frmUpload" action="../scripts/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="sermonInfo">
        File: <input type="file" id="uploadedFile" name="uploadedFile" class="error"><br>
        <br>
        Title: <input type="text" id="title" name="sermonTitle" size="35" maxlength="100">
    </div>
</form>
<div id="uploadInfo">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="statusBar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        <div class="percent">0%</div>
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="required">Only mp3 files are allowed!</div>
</div>
```

And here's the JS I'm using:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        /*
         * Upload
         */
        // Reset validation and progress elements
        var formValid = true,
            percentVal = '0%';
        $('#uploadedFile, #title').removeClass('error');
        $('#status, #required').empty().removeClass();
        $('.statusBar').width(percentVal)
        $('.percent').html(percentVal);

        $('form').ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function(e) {

                if (!ValidateUploadForm()) {
                    formValid = false;
                    console.log('validateuploadform returned false');
                } else {
                    console.log('validateuploadform returned true');
                    formValid = true;
                }

                console.log('in beforeSend. formValid: ' + formValid);

                if (!formValid) {
                    return false;
                }

            },
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                console.log('in uploadProgress function. formValid: ' + formValid);
                if (formValid) {
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    $('.statusBar').width(percentVal)
                    $('.percent').html(percentVal);    
                }
            },
            complete: function(xhr) {
                console.log('in complete function. formValid: ' + formValid);
                if (formValid) {
                    console.log('xhr.responseText: ' + xhr.responseText);
                    console.log('formValid: ' + formValid);

                    if (xhr.responseText === 'success') {
                        $('.statusBar').width('100%');
                        $('.percent').html('100%');
                        $('#status').html('Successfully uploaded the file.').addClass('successUpload');

                        // Clear the form
                        ClearForm();

                    } else if (xhr.responseText === 'fail') {
                        $('#status').html('There was a problem uploading the file. Try again.<br>If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.').addClass('errorUpload');
                    }
                }
            }
        }); // End Upload Status Bar
    });

    function ValidateUploadForm() {
        // Reset errors and clear message
        $('#uploadedFile, #title').removeClass('error');
        $('#required').empty();

        var result = true;
            title = $('#title').val(),
            fileName = $('#uploadedFile').val();
            extension = $('#uploadedFile').val().split('.').pop();

        if (fileName !== '' && extension !== 'mp3') {
            $('#uploadedFile').addClass('error');
            $('#required').html('Only mp3 files are allowed!');
            return false;
        } else if (fileName === '') {
            result = false;
        } else if (title === '') {
            $('#title').addClass('error');
            result = false;
        }

        console.log('returning ' + result + ' from the validateuploadform function');

        if (!result) { $('#required').html('All fields are required.'); }
            return result;
        }

        function ClearForm() {
            $('#uploadedFile, #title').val('').removeClass();
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, I'm using console output the keep an eye on what's going on.

My problem is, if a file is selected, the file still uploads, whether formValid (in beforeSend) is true or false.

I've tried adding preventDefault before `return false;`. I've also tried clearing the file input in the `if (!formValid) {}` block. As you can see, I've wrapped the `uploadProgress` and `complete` functions to check if formValid is false. If the console output in uploadProgress shows formValid to be **false**, the file still uploads.

What am I missing here? How can I prevent the file upload if the validation fails?

Comment: I really need some help on this, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue: I was comparing my script to some examples online and noticed that the examples' callback was named `beforeSubmit`, but I was using `beforeSend`.

Oddly, the validation code was still executing, but returning false didn't stop the upload.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it looks like you might be missing the `jquery.form.js` extension. Without JavaScript console output, I can only guess that that ought to be the problem. Try the following (entire) page as a reference, where stopping the upload works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
 div.c1 {width: 0%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmUpload" action="%3C?php%20basename(__FILE__,%20'.php');%20?%3E" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmUpload">
<div id="sermonInfo">File: <input type="file" id="uploadedFile" name="uploadedFile" class="error"><br>
<br>
Title: <input type="text" id="title" name="sermonTitle" size="35" maxlength="100"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
<div id="uploadInfo">
<div class="progress">
<div class="statusBar c1"></div>
<div class="percent">0%</div>
</div>
<div id="status"></div>
<br>
<div id="required">Only mp3 files are allowed!</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        /*
         * Upload
         */
        // Reset validation and progress elements
        var formValid = true,
            percentVal = '0%';
        $('#uploadedFile, #title').removeClass('error');
        $('#status, #required').empty().removeClass();
        $('.statusBar').width(percentVal)
        $('.percent').html(percentVal);

        $('form').ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function(e) {

                if (!ValidateUploadForm()) {
                    formValid = false;
                    console.log('validateuploadform returned false');
                } else {
                    console.log('validateuploadform returned true');
                    formValid = true;
                }

                console.log('in beforeSend. formValid: ' + formValid);

                if (!formValid) {
                    return false;
                }

            },
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                console.log('in uploadProgress function. formValid: ' + formValid);
                if (formValid) {
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    $('.statusBar').width(percentVal)
                    $('.percent').html(percentVal);    
                }
            },
            complete: function(xhr) {
                console.log('in complete function. formValid: ' + formValid);
                if (formValid) {
                    console.log('xhr.responseText: ' + xhr.responseText);
                    console.log('formValid: ' + formValid);

                    if (xhr.responseText === 'success') {
                        $('.statusBar').width('100%');
                        $('.percent').html('100%');
                        $('#status').html('Successfully uploaded the file.').addClass('successUpload');

                        // Clear the form
                        ClearForm();

                    } else if (xhr.responseText === 'fail') {
                        $('#status').html('There was a problem uploading the file. Try again.<br>If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.').addClass('errorUpload');
                    }
                }
            }
        }); // End Upload Status Bar
    });

    function ValidateUploadForm() {
        // Reset errors and clear message
        $('#uploadedFile, #title').removeClass('error');
        $('#required').empty();

        var result = true;
            title = $('#title').val(),
            fileName = $('#uploadedFile').val();
            extension = $('#uploadedFile').val().split('.').pop();

        if (fileName !== '' && extension !== 'mp3') {
            $('#uploadedFile').addClass('error');
            $('#required').html('Only mp3 files are allowed!');
            return false;
        } else if (fileName === '') {
            result = false;
        } else if (title === '') {
            $('#title').addClass('error');
            result = false;
        }

        console.log('returning ' + result + ' from the validateuploadform function');

        if (!result) { $('#required').html('All fields are required.'); }
            return result;
        }

        function ClearForm() {
            $('#uploadedFile, #title').val('').removeClass();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As a side note, you might want to use

```
extension = $('#uploadedFile').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
```

to make sure that the form also accepts `MP3`, as this is seen relatively often too in the wild.

If this doesn't fix your problem, it would help if you could upload the full HTML of one page in question.

**UPDATE**

With respect to the uploaded files, you have a simple typo in line 91 of `testUpload.php`:

```
if ((fileName === '') || (extension !== 'mp3'))
```

should be

```
if ((fileName === '') || (extension !== 'mp3')) {
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and providing the test code. I was including the form script remotely, as you did in your test code, but when I created a file locally with the form script it worked *differently* - not necessarily correctly.

The file isn't uploading on failed validation, but what's happening now is the action file is being loaded in the browser. Which I can't have happen - I need to stay on the upload form's page, obviously.

Your test upload form does the same thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you're actually using the same script locally? This might be caused by an actually different script, or by loading it **before** the `jquery` script in the DOM.

Comment: I made sure that the jquery.form script is being loaded after the jQuery script and I also tried copy/pasting the url you're using. But there must be something else going on here. The upload php script loads in the browser whether I use your test code or my own. I could upload the full files if it'd help, but since the same thing happens with your code as well as mine, I'm not sure if that would do any good.

Comment: As the decision to make another POST request is decided in the browser without any server interaction, I highly doubt that the server config is the primary difference here. Can you upload the source code (and all relevant prerequisites) of a page as it is served by your system?

Comment: I'd be glad to upload the code, but I'm not sure where exactly to do that in the question editor. I don't see anything indicating something that would allow me to upload files attached to this question.

Comment: If in doubt, try uploading it to http://plnkr.co/, then post the link in the original post.

Comment: Go to http://www.eventidewebdesign.com/public/testUpload/ the test file is testUpload.php and indexing is on for that folder, so you can check the files and see if an upload occurred or not (set to upload to "uploads/" folder)